# Upgrading sql server 2005 - to 2012 and effect on Hibernate applications

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Our systems are going to upgrade sql server from 2005 version to 2012.
The question, I have is:
Do I have to watch out for my applications using Hibernate ?  I know there will be no problems with native queries and queries going through regular JDBC.  However, is it potentially possible to need to change some JPA implementation code?  HQL queries?  etc?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think Hibernate uses to access the dataase? JDBC, and native queries.

Comment: "and queries going through regular JDBC" can do anything, including things specific to a version of SQL-Server. Most likely they won't do, but you can't generally rule it out.

Comment: @JBNizet , well .. I know that.  Was just curious if what it does internally is driver dependent (or not).  
And specific interest was: would I have to upgrade applications to the latest hibernate. ? Even if not to change a code, but just an upgrade. (undesirable in my case)